# Div's of equal height, flex and height not working?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've creating a block called `textCard` in `WPBakery`. The markup for this block is wrapped around default Bakery classes which is rending the markup like this:

```css
.textCard {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="container test d-flex">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="vc_column-inner">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
          <div class="textCard">
            <div class="textCard__container">
              <div class="textCard__content text-left">
                <h3>heading</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="vc_column-inner">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
          <div class="textCard">
            <div class="textCard__container">
              <div class="textCard__content text-left">
                <h3>This is heading</h3>
                <p>This is content</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="vc_column-inner">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
          <div class="textCard">
            <div class="textCard__container">
              <div class="textCard__content text-left">
                <h3>This is header</h3>
                <p>This is content</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Unsure why the above CSS works when the wrappers are removed:

```css
.textCard {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="container test d-flex">

    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="textCard">
        <div class="textCard__container">
          <div class="textCard__content text-left">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="textCard">
        <div class="textCard__container">
          <div class="textCard__content text-left">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="textCard">
        <div class="textCard__container">
          <div class="textCard__content text-left">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`.vc_column-inner` and `.wpb_wrapper` have no styles assigned to them so unsure what may be causing this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put your `textCard` in to a wrapper then force it to be 100% height, it will take 100% height of the parent wrapper, which in this case had the default property of `height: auto;` so it was collapsed.

> If height: auto; the element will automatically adjust its height to allow its content to be displayed correctly. - [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp)

The reason it worked when you took out the 2 wrappers is because the `col-sm-4` was full height as it got the property `align-items: stretch;` by default as its parent is `display: flex;`.

Simply adding a rule to make the wrappers 100% height of their parents as well as `textCard` fixes this issue.

[View CodePen](https://codepen.io/Kxrl/pen/BgboqV)

```css
.textCard {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
}

.vc_column-inner,
.wpb_wrapper,
.textCard {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="container test d-flex">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="vc_column-inner">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
          <div class="textCard">
            <div class="textCard__container">
              <div class="textCard__content text-left">
                <h3>heading</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="vc_column-inner">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
          <div class="textCard">
            <div class="textCard__container">
              <div class="textCard__content text-left">
                <h3>This is heading</h3>
                <p>This is content</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="vc_column-inner">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
          <div class="textCard">
            <div class="textCard__container">
              <div class="textCard__content text-left">
                <h3>This is header</h3>
                <p>This is content</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because your styling is no longer affected by actual height, since it's nested with two `<div>`elements. Following style should be child of `class="col-sm-4"`

Change style to

```
.vc_column-inner {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}
```

or move `<div class="textCard">` under `<div class="col-sm-4">`

Answer (score 0):

If i've understood correctly, you don't need to use the bootstrap `.col-4` class if you're using `display:flex`.

You've set the height of the items to be 100% and as `display:flex` so that means they'll fit the 100% height.

However this happens by default if you set the `.container` to `display:flex` and the children `.textCard` to `flex:1` they'll all display equal. The children are set as `align-items: stretch` by default due to their flex container.

See codepen here, hope that's what you meant!
https://codepen.io/Robhern135/pen/LKaGVL